# Parse XML from Sonos

Tags: node.js, xml

I am trying to parse the XML output from Sonos subscription I am doing this in Node.js
I have tried two different npm modules, xml2js and libxmljs but i cant seem to get it right.
All example that I have find is a simple XML but I am trying to parse a more advanced file and probably not much harder when you know how to handle it.

I hope someone could help me so that I understand how to tackle a file like this.
In my example then I want the value 22 from:

```
<Volume channel="Master" val="22"/>
```

Here is the XML file

```
<e:propertyset
xmlns:e="urn:schemas-upnp-org:event-1-0">
<e:property>
    <LastChange>
        <Event
            xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/RCS/">
            <InstanceID val="0">
                <Volume channel="Master" val="22"/>
                <Volume channel="LF" val="100"/>
                <Volume channel="RF" val="100"/>
                <Mute channel="Master" val="0"/>
                <Mute channel="LF" val="0"/>
                <Mute channel="RF" val="0"/>
                <Bass val="0"/>
                <Treble val="0"/>
                <Loudness channel="Master" val="1"/>
                <OutputFixed val="0"/>
                <HeadphoneConnected val="0"/>
                <SpeakerSize val="5"/>
                <SubGain val="0"/>
                <SubCrossover val="0"/>
                <SubPolarity val="0"/>
                <SubEnabled val="1"/>
                <SonarEnabled val="0"/>
                <SonarCalibrationAvailable val="0"/>
                <PresetNameList val="FactoryDefaults"/>
            </InstanceID>
        </Event>
    </LastChange>
</e:property>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var DOMParser = require('xmldom').DOMParser;
var xmltext = `<e:propertyset xmlns:e="urn:schemas-upnp-org:event-1-0">
    <e:property>
        <LastChange>
            <Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/RCS/">
                <InstanceID val="0">
                    <Volume channel="Master" val="22"/>
                    <Volume channel="LF" val="100"/>
                    <Volume channel="RF" val="100"/>
                    <Mute channel="Master" val="0"/>
                    <Mute channel="LF" val="0"/>
                    <Mute channel="RF" val="0"/>
                    <Bass val="0"/>
                    <Treble val="0"/>
                    <Loudness channel="Master" val="1"/>
                    <OutputFixed val="0"/>
                    <HeadphoneConnected val="0"/>
                    <SpeakerSize val="5"/>
                    <SubGain val="0"/>
                    <SubCrossover val="0"/>
                    <SubPolarity val="0"/>
                    <SubEnabled val="1"/>
                    <SonarEnabled val="0"/>
                    <SonarCalibrationAvailable val="0"/>
                    <PresetNameList val="FactoryDefaults"/>
                </InstanceID>
            </Event>
        </LastChange>
    </e:property>
    </e:propertyset>`;

var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString( xmltext, "application/xml" );
var docElem = doc.documentElement;
var Volume = docElem.getElementsByTagName('Volume');
//console.log(Volume.toString());
//Volume.length;  //3

console.log(Volume[0].getAttribute("val"));     //'22'
console.log(Volume[0].getAttribute("channel")); //'Master'
```

Comment: Thanks.
That was a very simple solution and it works great.